# Flask socket io does not work from another class module

Tags: flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio, emit

I have a Flask application that sends data through websocket with emit.

My Python code looks like this. I want the emit to be triggerd in AnotherClass at some conditions.

```
class MainClass:
    def __init__(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.secret_key = 'any random string'
        self.socketio = SocketIO(app, logger=True, binary=True, engineio_logger=True,
                                 always_connect=True, async_mode='eventlet')
        self.socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
        self.socketio.on_event('on-record', self.record, namespace='/audio')
        self.AC = AnotherClass(socketio=self.socketio)
        
    def run_app(self):
        self.socketio.run(self.app, debug=True, port=8000)

    def record(self, some_other_data):
        # This function gets triggered when client emit
        # I inserted the following emit to test if this works
        self.socketio.emit('send-data', {'data': data}, namespace='/audio')
        
       

class AnotherClass:
    def __init__(self, socketio):
        self.socketio = socketio
 
    def send_data(self, data):
        self.socketio.emit('send-data', {'data': data}, namespace='/audio')
```

When I trigger the emit function from AnotherClass.send_data, I get the following log that says the emit works and sending the data, however, the client-side application does not receive the data. On the contrary, the same emit works in the MainClass.record which is the event gets triggered when the client emits something. (I inserted the emit to test in which case works, ideally, it should not be in record function.)

```
cedb89204e80438da86361a97f6f1bac: Sending packet MESSAGE data 51-/audio,["send-data",{"data":{"_placeholder":true,"num":0}}]. cedb89204e80438da86361a97f6f1bac: Sending packet MESSAGE data <binary>
```

This is the JavaScript code that receives the emit from the Python script above.

```
var socketio = io.connect('0.0.0.0:8000' + '/audio', {transports: ['websocket']});

socketio.on("send-data", function(data) {
    // Log when client receives the data from server-side
    console.log("Data received");
    }
})
```

Could anyone please give me any insights on what I am doing wrongly?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code that you posted, as far as I can see. There is really no way to detect which class is calling `emit()`, so if outside of the originating class all other things are the same this should have worked. I get that you are sure this isn't a client problem, but still, you should add your client code to the question, and also add the working case. Somewhere there must be a difference that you are not considering.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and it definitely makes sense. I will add the working code and the client code.

Comment: I have updated the question with the working case and the client code. It would be great if you could give some insights into the updated codes as I might have been overlooking something on the codes.

Comment: There is still nothing evidently wrong. I believe you are still not explaining the difference between these two accurately. For example, while you provided good detail regarding how the working emit is triggered, you've said nothing regarding the emit in the auxiliary class, and none of the code you showed calls that either.